# calling server (ajax request) multiple times in angular 2 leads to 500 internal server error

Tags: angular, typescript

in a function i am doing a http post and returning the result as below using angular 2 with typescript

```
return this.http.post(url, body, {
         headers: headers
       })
       .toPromise()
       .then(data => {
          var json = data.json();
          return json;
       })
       .catch(error =>
         this.HandleError(error));`
```

but for first 2-3 times it works fine after which it gives 500 Internal server error
continuously called 5 times the same action. did anyone face similar kind of issue?

Comment: Internal server error is an error caused by your server. You need to investigate there.

Comment: yes its caused by the server but its not happening at the first time. first 2 times the same thing works but from the third or fourth time it gives error where nothing has changed. same call with same server

Comment: Then the server doesn't handle concurrent requests well. There is no point in diagnosing the problem from client side code.